# What is the benefit of humroth (stringencies)?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, stringency-chumrah, nozir

If we are meant to understand from the *Nazir* that forbidding things which are really *mutar* in order to be "extra holy" is really not a positive thing (cf. y.*Nedarim* 9:1), then of what benefit are *humroth* (if any)? Or are we simply misunderstanding what a *humra* actually is as spoken of by *Hazal* (the same rabbanim who told us the lesson of the *Nazir*)?

Comment: Is it so bad to be a nazir? http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=63&format=text

Comment: mesilat yesharim says it is to be yotze all the opinions, kind of like going the extra mile for the Boss

Comment: Are you asking what we get from observing chumros, or what makes chumros more desirable to G-d (if they are), or merely looking for a source for observing chumros? (For example: "אמר רבא קדש עצמך במותר לך" -[Yevamos 20a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=20&format=pdf) ) Also, regarding your first assumption, don't forget the gemara in [Taanis 11a-b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=11&format=pdf), where the Amoraim discuss whether voluntary fasts are good or bad, using kal vachomers from the nazir.

Comment: The Talmud in Nedarim 10A also brings opinions that a Nazir is a good thing. See this article for a possible reconciliation: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/AID/2243/ShowFeedback/true

Comment: Can you perhaps better define what you mean by "Humroth"?

Answer (score 5):

There are different types of Chumrot, as I see it.

***1. Fence***

Sometimes we (personal or dictated by Chazal) need a fence to keep us away from the actual transgression. This way, if we stumble we hit the fence and don't fall into the pit of sin. This is the fence referred to - **and recommended** - in the first Mishna in Pirkei Avot.

This is your typical Humra.

An example (dictated by Chazal) would be: not having some people eat meat and others milk at the same table.

An example (personal) would be: not relying on the Eruv in case it's broken.

***2. Holiness***

There's a concept of being holy והייתם קדושים - which includes refraining from doing things that are permitted, in order to reach a higher level of closeness to Hashem.

The concept of Nazir seems like "an example provided by the Torah" of the second concept. And here we learn a lesson - that it's better to learn how to **use** "everything" in the service of Hashem rather than *outlawing* them.

Some things - like meat and wine - are needed only in *very small* quantities in the service of Hashem. But refraining from them completely - in order not to over-indulge - is not the recommended way, as per the lessons of Nazir.

The better way is to learn how to control yourself; that helps you reach a higher level of closeness to Hashem.

Comment: The Nesivos famously says ([Choshen Mishpat 234:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14541&st=&pgnum=312), also see [this](http://jewishworker.blogspot.com/2006/09/do-you-need-to-do-teshuva-for.html)) that one gets no onesh for violating a derabanan b'shogeig. If one is halachically permitted to rely on an eiruv, say, because of a chazaka, and even if the eiruv turns out to be passul there is no onesh, what is the point of not relying on it? Isn't that similar to the case of nazir making assur for himself what is muttar?

Comment: @Malper, that is not a universally held [opinion](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14543&st=&pgnum=50&hilite=).

Comment: There is at least a third category, regarding being choshed to opinions that are not strictly the halacha. Like pretty much everything that is permitted when there is great loss, but not otherwise.

Comment: @Malper - why would relying on an Eruv be dependent on Chazaka? What kind of Chazaka do strings have "out in the open". And why do you link carrying without an Eiruv to D'Rabanan? Not sure that's universal...

Comment: @DannySchoemann I think chezkas kashrus applies to eruvin but AYLO. And carrying in a karmelis is d'rabanan.

Comment: @Malper - why would our wide thoroughfares be considered a karmelis?

Comment: @DannySchoemann You can't have an eruv around a reshus d'rabim. See [this article](http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1482).

Answer (score 2):

The [סידור מהרי"ד](http://www.heichal.co.il/english/products/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93_2_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D/808) at the beginning of his explanation on Pirkei Avos compares Humroth to protection around a precious pearl. The more precious the pearl, the more layers of protection it is provided. Similarly, by keeping Humroth, we are showing how precious the Mitzvos are to us.

So Humroth have a purpose, even if they forbid things which are permitted.  They have a positive aspect and a negative one, and depending on the circumstances it depends which one is controlling.

Comment: So what about the principle of "Kol mosif gorea`"? If what you referenced is correct, then how do the two things work together?

Comment: @Maimonist, בקצור נמרץ - when the Humerah is according to the Torah, then it isn't Mosif. e.g. עשו סייג לתורה, משמרת למשמרתי, Hilchos Deios 2:[3-4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1202.htm) etc.

Comment: These references are to instituted safeguards made by an active Sanhedrin." In fact, according to the Rambam in the Mishneh Torah, a "humrah" is merely taking the stricter of two opinions in an honest doubt about a Torah law, , not finding ways to be more "frum" about things in which there is no real doubt. We show how precious the misswoth are to us when we perform them, not by abstaining from things which are permitted for the sake of being mahmir. Such a path actually shows our disrespect of the misswoth. (cf. Hilkhoth De`oth 3).

Comment: And your reference to the "holei nefesh" of Hilkhoth De`oth 2:3-4 is not really relevant to this discussion since he defines the therapy of the "holei nefesh" as a hakham prescribing certain ways to fix ailing character traits. This has nothing to do with humroth at all. In fact, if you read the overall context of that chapter - and Hilkhoth De`oth as a whole - you will see that the entire goal of all character development and Torah education is to follow the "middle road" and the "golden mean" - not to be mahmir.

Comment: @Maimonist, Sanhedrin doesn't have an issue of "Kol mosif gorea"? || That can't be the only definition of Chumra according to the Rambam, see Issurei Biah 11 (which has a counter example of requiring a Sanhedrin as well i.e. Takkanos from Geonim) || Chumras have multiple purposes and sources, but one is for personal development, which was my point. As long as the purpose and source is in the Torah, it has a place. If not, not.

Comment: I was in no way suggesting by my comments that the Sanhedrin had an issue of "Kol mosif gorea`." Your equivocation of the two is telling, however, in this discussion. And your proof from Hilkhoth Isurei Bi'ah 11 is no proof, but rather only serves to prove my point. The Banoth Yisra'el were stringent on themselves in matters of nidduth and zivuth because there arose doubts regarding the distinctions between the two and thus they were strict in a matter of Torah law which was in doubt. Humroth generally do not have a source in Torah, which is why the hakhamim were asked to make them.

Comment: @Maimonist, my point is that they don't have the issue of "Kol mosif gorea" because of the posuk, not because they are inherently exempt. || This Q&A thread has generated 6 Torah sources for Chumras 1) Sanhedrin 2) Beis Din 3) Sofek about Halacha 4) Minhag adopted by non-Rabbonim/Beis Din to avoid Issurim 5) Holiness (והייתם קדושים) and 6) Private chumras to fix "cholei HaNefesh" (some might call that a "tikkun"). We could probably add more if we worked at it. All of that has a source (as in precedent and basis) in Torah. Going beyond that "is kol hamosif gorea" and even within that ...

Comment: @Maimonist ... Nazir shows that it isn't always ideal. Having been sick and requiring drastic measures still requires Teshuva.

Comment: I know that you keep quoting sources, but I continue to argue on them because it is obvious that you have referenced them in error and/or misunderstand them - with the exception, perhaps, of the Lubavitch siddur you cited. In other words, they really do not support your conclusions and you refuse to answer my counter-questions. So, it seems we have reached a stalemate.

Comment: @Maimonist, what counter question have I refused to answer?

Comment: As is our usual custom, we have reached an impasse. The fact is that we come from two completely different worlds and our understanding of Torah is - dare I say - diametrically opposed, and on almost every level. I am frankly not interested in dogmatic statements about what Judaism supposedly teaches made from the writings of Hasidism. Our impasses are generally as a result of the fact that I do not deem such "sources" as admissible in halakhic or hashkafic discussions. I have no more desire to discuss this with you here. Shabbath Shalom.